# php variable in scope but still getting undefined variable error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

earlier i posted question here but i have found the solution myself now i have weird problem i am using FormData() and passing it to another php page using ajax but my all variables are undefined even though it is in scope but still i am getting this error here is my php code

```
    <?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['recaptcha'])){
        $secret = "**********";
        $response = $_POST['recaptcha'];
        $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteip");
        $content = json_decode($url, TRUE);
        if($content['success'] ==1){
            function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            $data = strtolower($data);
            return $data;
            }
            $discount = test_input($_POST["discount"]);
            $discountitem = test_input($_POST["discountitem"]);
            $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
            $expirydate = test_input($_POST["expirydate"]);
            $desc = test_input($_POST["desc"]);
            $filename;
            if(isset($_FILES['logouploader']['name'])){
                $filename = basename($_FILES['logouploader']['name']);
                $filename = test_input($filename);
            }
            $dir = "img/uploads/";
            $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['logouploader']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $allowed =  array('jpeg','png' ,'jpg');
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
                echo "wrongext";
                $uploadOk = 0;
                exit;
            }
            if ($_FILES["logouploader"]["size"] > 600000) {
                echo "large";
                $uploadOk = 0;
                exit;
            }
            $uploadOk = 1;
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry";
                exit;
            }
            if ($uploadOk == 1) {
                $emailfromdb = $_SESSION['email']; //getting session variable
                function logoset (){
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "*****";
                    $password = "*******";
                    try {
                        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dineandparty_dineandparty", $username, $password);
                        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                        $fkid = "SELECT id from dineOwnerUser WHERE email = ?";
                        $statement = $conn->prepare($fkid);
                        $statement -> execute (
                            array(
                            $emailfromdb
                        ));
                        $ownerid = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $query = "INSERT INTO webpromo (discount, dealitem, website, expirydate, description, ,logouploader, ownerid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                        $statement->execute(
                            array(
                            $discount, //undefined variable
                            $discountitem, //undefined variable
                            $website, //undefined variable
                            $expirydate, //undefined variable
                            $desc, //undefined variable
                            $filename, //undefined variable
                            $ownerid //undefined variable
                            ) );
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logouploader"]["tmp_name"], $dir.$filename);
                            $conn = null;
                            echo "done";
                            exit;
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }

                function nologoset() {
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "************";
                    $password = "*************";
                    try {
                        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=dineandparty_dineandparty", $username, $password);
                        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                        $query = "INSERT INTO webpromo (discount, dealitem, website, expirydate, description, logouploader, ownerid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
                        $statement->execute(
                            array(
                            $discount,
                            $discountitem,
                            $website,
                            $expirydate,
                            $desc,
                            $filename
                            ) );
                            $conn = null;
                            echo "done";
                            exit;
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
                if(isset($_FILES['logouploader']['name'])){
                logoset();
                }
                if(!isset($_FILES['logouploader']['name'])){
                    nologoset();
                }
            }
        }
        if($content['success'] !=1){
            echo "notok";
            $conn = null;
            exit;
        }
        $conn = null;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

and my jquery code is this just in case you need to see the code

```
        $("#promotionsubmit").click(function(){
            if((discounterr != "no") || (discountitemerr != "no") || (expirydateerr != "no") ||(descerr != "no")){
                errbox = $("#robotError");
                errcontent = "All * fields are mandatory";
                showerror(errbox, errcontent);
            }
            if((discounterr == "no") && (discountitemerr == "no") && (expirydateerr =="no") && (descerr == "no")){
                errbox = $("#robotError");
                errcontent = " ";
                hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append("discount",discount);
                fd.append("discountitem",discountitem);
                fd.append("website",website);
                fd.append("expirydate",expirydate);
                fd.append("desc",desc);
                fd.append("logouploader",logouploader);
                fd.append("recaptcha",grecaptcha.getResponse());
            $.ajax({
                url:"promotionform.php",
                method:"POST",
                data : fd,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == "notok"){
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        errbox = $("#robotError");
                        errcontent = "please verify you are not robot";
                        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
                    }
                    if(data == "large"){
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        errbox = $("#robotError");
                        errcontent = "image is larger than 600 kb. Allowed size is 600 kb for logo";
                        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
                    }
                    if(data == "wrongext"){
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        errbox = $("#robotError");
                        errcontent = "only jpg, jpeg and png are allowed for logo";
                        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
                    }
                    if(data == "notimage"){
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        errbox = $("#robotError");
                        errcontent = "file is not an image";
                        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
                    }
                    if(data == "Sorry"){
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        errbox = $("#robotError");
                        errcontent = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
                        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
                    }
                    if(data == "done"){
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        errbox = $("#robotError");
                        errcontent = " ";
                        hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
                        window.location='http://domainname.com/';
                    }
                }
            });
            }
        });
```

i have checked my coding several times but i really don't know why my php variables are undefined.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. It should be `fd.append()`

Comment: thank you for comment @Emerald i was following this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append and i was trying to pass this like formData.append(name, value);

If you know any good tutorial website so please recommend me i will be very thankful. Actually i want to make compatible with i.e8 or i.e9 too. Do you know how to achieve same functionality without fordata();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are perhaps confusing Javascript scoping with PHP's. The variables you complain about are **not** in the scope of the `logoset` function, as they are declared earlier, yes, but outside.

For them to be in scope, you need to pull them in with **`use`**:

```
 $logoset = function() use ($discount, $discountitem, ...) {
```

or declare them `global` (which isn't recommended - google "*polluting the global scope*").

```
 function logoset () {
     global $discount, $discountitem, ...
```

## Experimenting

You can experiment with scoping like this:

```
$iAmGlobal = true;

function test() {
    $iAmLocal = true;
    $used = true;

    $inside = function() use ($used, $usedAfter) {
        print_r(get_defined_vars());
    };
    $usedAfter = true;
    call_user_func($inside);
}

test();
```

The results are:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: usedAfter on line 9
Array
(
    [used] => 1
    [usedAfter] =>
)
```

So, the variable in the use clause *must already be defined*, and if it is not, it gets defined by force - but it's empty.

The `$iAmGlobal` variable is not visible, nor is `$iAmLocal`. But if you had put `global $iAmGlobal;` inside the inner function, then you would see that `$iAmGlobal` becomes visible. Doing this with `$iAmLocal` **does not work** (because that variable is not global) unless you force it with a second global declaration inside `test()`.

Comment: thank you for teaching me. I am following w3schools php tutorial in there they are saying we can use variable if we declared them in global scope. Is not my variable in global scope ?

Comment: It is, but that is not enough. You need to use `global` for that use case.

Comment: can i use this ? 
$GLOBALS['discount'] = test_input($_POST["discount"]);
$GLOBALS['discountitem'] = test_input($_POST["discountitem"]);
$GLOBALS['website'] = test_input($_POST["website"]);
$GLOBALS['expirydate'] = test_input($_POST["expirydate"]);
$GLOBALS['desc'] = test_input($_POST["desc"]);
$GLOBALS['filename'];

Comment: i used same as you described now i am getting error 
[04-Mar-2018 14:20:36 America/Montreal] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{' in /home/dineandparty/public_html/promotionform.php on line 47

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke - you can only use `use` in anonymous function context. Edited answer.